# RotateLog with powershell

Tags: powershell, logrotate

I am new to scripting and Powershell, and I am trying to create a script to keep every day the log files of the 3 last days only

```
function RotateLog {
$dir="C:\Users\user1\Documents\Project\LOG"
$DayMax= -3
$CurrentDate= Get-Date -uformat "%d-%m-%Y-%H%M"
$DatetoDelete= (get-date -UFormat "%d-%m-%Y-%H%M").AddDays($DayMax)

get-childitem -path $dir -filter "YYYY-mm-dd-*.LOG"
foreach-object {
if ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete)
{remove-item}
}
}
```

When I run $DatetoDelete it returns *failed because [System.String] does  not contain a method named 'AddDays'.*

So I tried to replace the variable by

```
$dtt=(get-date).AddDays($DayMax)
```

It is working this way, but I need to get the format .
How can I do it ?

Another problem, when I run the command `remove-item`, it returns *cmdlet remove-item at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:path[0]*
What does it mean ?

Comment: for comparing things, use `[datetime]` _objects_ ... NEVER convert them to date time _strings_ for anything other than display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Format` and `-UFormat` parameters make `Get-Date` output a *string representation* of the corresponding `[datetime]` object, and "adding -3 days to a string" doesn't make much sense.

Use `Get-Date` *without* a format parameter to get a `[datetime]` object that can be meaningfully modified and compared instead:

```bsh
# Get current date and time as a [datetime] object
$CurrentDate = Get-Date

# Here I reference the `Date` property on our DateTime object
# this gives us the same date, but at 00:00 local time
$DateToDelete = $CurrentDate.Date.AddDays($DayMax)
```

Now, `$_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete` makes a lot more sense, as we're comparing `[datetime]` to `[datetime]` rather than to a formatted string